Why do we have both npm and npx commands?
I have always been confused about these.  A quick Google search tells you that npm is for package management, e. g., installing and deleting packages whereas npx is for package execution.  I am already slightly annoyed.  Why do we need an extra command to execute a package? What was wrong with just running the package with its name (possibly having to add it to the path manually or activating some sort of a virtual environment).
But, as all things Javascript, that was not really the answer.  Upon further Googling, it seemed that the real reason we have npm and npx is because sometimes we want to quickly execute a package without installing it such that we execute its latest version. Examples being the packages that setup projects.
I see but then there is an additional kicker, we also have npm create package.  Okay--what is that now? This answer says that npm create package is an undocumented shorthand for npx create-package.  Wait, shorthand?  The former is literally only one character shorter than the latter...
It also seems npm create is the same as npm init.
Am I just confused or is it really this convoluted and messy?

People just don't like it when you question Javascript and party...

Historical reasons and backwards compatibility.
npx was originally an unofficial package written by Kat Marchán, who worked at npm on the CLI team. Its core feature wasn't create, it was to execute things in npm bin without typing them out (meaning ./node_modules/.bin/ in a project, or your global node_modules/bin). A secondary feature (but the one you're talking about) is running a remote (uninstalled) package's bin, so if there's a package called create-react-app, it can run whatever's in the bin obj in its package.json.
Importantly though, this also works for other types of packages. You can run npx ts-node foo.ts without having ts-node installed anywhere on your machine, for example.
npm init (alias npm create) is a little different. Without a specified package, it inits a new project. With a package specifier (like create-react-app, it'll find that package and run its bin scripts. It doesn't work with other types of packages, it only cares about create-foo and will try to prepend that if you don't pass it (for example, if you do npm create html2txt, you'll get a 404).
To make that even more confusing, we also have npm exec, which does the same things as npx, just with different flag order. npx itself ships with npm, and is just a ~100 line wrapper over the exec subcommand.
At this point I'm not sure why they haven't been merged, but my guess is to avoid breaking millions of users' scripts.
